# Does writing of the big file block Erlang VM?

Tags: erlang

Does the entire Erlang VM get blocked (that is no other Erlang processes are executed) while I write a big file in a separate process ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Erlang VM manages an internal (OS-level) thread pool for I/O. 
Interacting with files will not block the emulator.

In general, file access goes through an IoDevice, which is a wrapper process coordinating I/O. If you work with files a lot, this may slow things down.
`file:open/2` provides a `raw` mode for faster, direct reading/writing of files.